# Android Programmatically setting button text

Tags: android, button

Does anybody know how to programmatically set the text of a button?

thing is i'm not calling this from the main layout(setContentView) i'm calling it in a view thats inflated after an asynctask
heres what i have tried but this is giving a null pointer exception on the 2nd line

```
Button mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.contact);
        mButton.setText("number");
```

heres my layout where i am calling the button

```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/contact"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/address"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/badge"
       android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_call"
       android:textSize="10dp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

here my view i'm inflating

```
ClubInfo = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.clubinfocell,
                null);

        TextView TeamNameText = (TextView) ClubInfo.findViewById(R.id.TeamName);
        TeamNameText.setText(teamName);

        TextView AddressText = (TextView) ClubInfo.findViewById(R.id.address);
        AddressText.setText(address1);



        Button mButton=(Button)ClubInfo.findViewById(R.id.contact);
        mButton.setText(telephone);
```

Comment: can you post your full onCreate method here?

Comment: please provide your full java code file.

Comment: It gives NPE because mButton is null on first line. And that's is because findViewById didn't find a R.id.contact you provided to it.

Comment: Problem will not be in the java file, but in the xml

Comment: Does textViews work correctly? If so, what is the difference between your TextViews and your Button in code/xml?

Comment: you shouldn't use getBaseContext() for that. change it to YourActivityName.this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Then use your view's object to initialize it:

```
Button mButton = (Button)your_view_object.findViewById(R.id.contact);
mButton.setText("number");
```

When you try to identify a view other than your Activity's layout, you have to pass the reference of that view like this.  If not Android will keep looking for this element from the layout which you provided in the `setContentView()`.

For example, consider you have inflated a view like this:

```
View View = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridelement, null);
```

Then use this View's object for the Button present in that inflated layout:

```
  Button mButton = (Button)View.findViewById(R.id.contact);
```

Comment: i have edited my code to show my view i'm still getting null pointer exception

Comment: Try surrounding this, with null check, if(mButton!=null) {  mButton.setText(telephone);}

Answer (score 2):

change your code as:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);//set layout here in which u have add contact in xml
        Button mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.contact);
        mButton.setText("number");
```

**EDIT:**
Your \res\layout\main.xml look like as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
       android:id="@+id/contact"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/address"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/badge"
       android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_call"
       android:textSize="10dp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="@color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: problem is its not been loaded from the content view its a button within a inflated view that i have inflated after an Asynctask

Comment: @LukeBatley : as your question u are getting all right answers.if problem is not solved then post more code and full explain of problem

Comment: @LukeBatley : use `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
View ClubInfo=inflater.inflate(R.layout.clubinfocell, null);  ` instead of  `ClubInfo = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.clubinfocell,
                null); `

Answer (score 1):

your `mButton` is null.so NPE.are you refrenced xml resources after `setContentView`

```
onCreate(){
...
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

Button mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.contact);
mButton.setText("number");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check R.java files import statement

are you sure that you have import it of the project you use ..
and just format your layout (.xml ) file save it and again type the same statement