# Create or change an xml button using xml text field and javascript

Tags: javascript, android, xml, brackets

I'm developing an android application, I want a button to appear with the button text being whatever the user inputs into a text field. Confused on how to achieve  this.

Comment: Try searching for a tutorial online, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154898/android-programmatically-setting-button-text

Comment: This question is unrelated to the Atom editor, so there's no need to add a tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

lets take an example that you have two buttons defined in the xml 
one to click on and one to appear later. make the second button invisible using the android:visibilty=invisible and then in the click listener of the first button do something like this.

```
yourbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
          String incomingText =  yourEditText.getText().toString();
          invisibleButton.setText(incomingText);
          invisibleButton.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        });
```